# Path.op freezes GUI in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

In my App the user can draw on a Canvas with their finger. During onTouch event I would like to call Path.op to check for an intersection.

The result: GUI freezes and App does Not react for further interactions. No error or Logcat message.

What might cause this and how can I prevent freezing the GUI?

**Edit:**
My source code in onTouchEvent() and the used method:

```
 private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    if (activeListener && !copy){
    broadcastData(pathToByteArray(x/getScreenWidth(),y/getScreenHeight(),(byte)'M'));
    }
    else if (activeListener && copy){
        path.add(new PaintPath(x,y));
    }
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        //totalPath = mPath;
        totalPath = new Path(mPath);
         mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
         lastPath = new Path(mPath);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        circlePath.reset();
        circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        // This causes the error
        lastPath.op(totalPath,Path.Op.DIFFERENCE);
        if (lastPath.op(totalPath, Path.Op.INTERSECT)){
            Log.e("Intersection","Intersection");
        }    
        // End of the problem
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (activeListener){
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (activeListener){
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            }
            break;
            ...
```

Comment: show your code in onTouchEvent

Comment: add your code here. It can be too many process on your main thread

Comment: added the souce code and commented the part which causes the error